# Rails Assets precompile on the air

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a web where user can configure the background image, for that i use js.erb file in assets folder.

But, when user change preferences the application need to precompe assets, because in a function within application.js.erb I have something like:

Body.css("background-image",url('<%= Preference.first.bg_image url%>')

Is there a way to precompile assets "on execution"... In a controller or a model..

Other way I was thinking, is use oldstyle js, a .js.erb file in public folder, js not in assets system

I think I am missing something "big"

Thanks

Pd: I use javascript because I use transitions with other images, animations... Etc

I don't want to use image_tag in a html.erb because of control between transitions with other backgorunds images

Comment: Have you thought about not precompiling assets? Or at least requiring the dynamic assets separately?. Other option might be to look for a "data" attribute on some tag and then adding an "on_change callback" to trigger the change in background once data attribute changes

Comment: First, yes, when I say " Other way I was thinking, is use oldstyle js, a .js.erb file in public folder, js not in assets system

 "

Comment: The second comment, it colud be an option, thanks, I didn't know if I was missing something obvious